# delete notification from android

Tags: android, notifications

I want to give option of deleting my notification in the activity which gets opened after clicking it from notification bar.  I am using the following code:

```
nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Log.i(TAG, "after NotificationManager");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,test.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("subject", subject);
        intent.putExtra("notificationid", count);
        Log.i(TAG, title);
        Log.i(TAG, subject);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, count, intent,0);



        Notification n = new  Notification(R.drawable.icon,subject,System.currentTimeMillis());

        n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, subject, pi);
        n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

        nm.notify(count, n);
```

And my test.java looks like this:

```
public class test extends Activity {


    TextView Title;
    TextView Subject;
    Button Clear;
    protected int notificationid;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);  

        String title="";
        String subject="";



        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extras !=null) {
             title = extras.getString("title");
             subject = extras.getString("subject");
             notificationid = extras.getInt("notificationid");
        }
        Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Title);
        Subject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Subject);
        Title.setText(title);
        Subject.setText(subject);
      Clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {     

                  NotificationManager nm ;
                 nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), " onClick inside test caled....");
                nm.cancel(notificationid);


            }
        });

    }
}
```

But application is getting closed unexpectedly.  Can anyone help me out in this?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing

```
Clear=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ClearButtonId);
```

this in your `test` Class ?

It must be the problem. You might be getting `NullPointerException` as you have not parsed the `Button` component and you are trying to use it directly.

Comment: @Kartik, +1 from me. XYZ, you might still want to follow Kyle's suggestion and make sure you set up LogCat. This will make finding future problems much easier :-)

Answer (score 1):

What is the error associated with the unexpected code?  Can you give details on the exception causing the crash?

Do you use LogCat?  If not, check out http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html. To view the logcat logs directly in the command prompt, open the command prompt and go to the directory where your android sdk is found.  Run `adb logcat`.  You should start seeing a printout of the errors, warnings, etc. generated by logcat.

Once you're able to see what the problem is using logcat (it will tell you NullPointerException, ResourceNotFoundException, etc and the line of code that caused the problem), if you can't figure out the source of the crash from that then paste the error info here.

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see your LogCat output, it's hard to tell what exactly the error is, but from looking at the code (this may of course be wrong if you've only pasted partial code), you're not initialising your `notificationid` variable in the case where `extras == null`. If you're developing with Eclipse, have a look in the LogCat view and find the error stacktrace.

Edit after seeing Kyle's answer: what he said about LogCat ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL:

```
n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if the notification should be canceled when it is clicked by the user.